# vim-latex shortcuts

Tags: vim

I am facing a problem for using shortcuts provided by vim-latex. Say, I
want `\textbf`, so I was trying `` `bf ``.

But, given, `` `b `` is a shortcut for
`\beta`, I always end up with something `\betaf`.

FBF works, how can I use `` `bf ``?
any help?

Answer (score 2):

The `vim-latex` plugin uses its own implementation of the `:imap` command, which here is responsible for detecting patterns that should be replaced.

According to the [documentation](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/ls-new-macros.html), the timeout functionality of `:imap`, which would have allowed it to wait some time before checking for known patterns and allowing your usage of `` `bf `` was removed in `vim-latex‘` own `IMAP()` function to allow for slower typing while still recognizing patterns.

`IMAP()` does not have the ability to wait until you probably finished typing and instead tries to match what it sees *right now*.

*Currently, I have no idea as to how one would either add that functionality to `IMAP()` or use its mappings with `:imap`.*

So, simply put, this happens because `` `b `` gets already replaced before you type `f`.

---

Or as the section `3.12 Making your own Macros via IMAP()` of the [`vim-latex documentation`](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/ls-new-macros.html) puts it:

> If you have two mappings which end in a common `lhs`, then the mapping with the longer `lhs` is used. For example, if you do
>
> `call IMAP('BarFoo', 'something', 'tex')`
>
> `call IMAP('Foo', 'something else', 'tex')`
>
> Then typing `BarFoo` inserts `"something"`, whereas `Foo` by itself inserts `"something else"`.
>
> Also, the nature of `IMAP()` makes creating certain combination of mappings impossible. For example if you have
>
> `call IMAP('foo', 'something', 'tex')`
>
> `call IMAP('foobar', 'something else', 'tex')`
>
> Then you will never be able to trigger `"foobar"` because typing `"foo"` will immediately insert `"something"`. This is the "cost" which you incur over the normal `:imap` command for the convenience of no 'timeout' problems, the ability to correct `lhs` etc.

---

Using `IMAP()` you could try looking into `~/.vim/ftplugin/latex-suite/main.vim` and adjust the mappings to your convenience with the above explained restrictions. 
For example make the following changes:
line 93 `b` → `bg`
and add a definition for `bf`.
*I am not entirely sure, that `bg` is unused by default. And the above would break the consistency of the greek-letter-mappings.*